# Extracting specific values of an atomic vecor to a new vector

Tags: r

I have a huge dataset and I want to do some Statistical analysis with R.
In order to do that, I need for instance from a vector extract all specific values to a new vector. 
For instance `V = c("J","J","J","N","N")`
I would like to get all `J`'s to a new one say `P = c("J","J","J")`. Is there any function for that?
Also in the same way, for index `i` that is `J`, I want to extract the value in another vector `K` to `D`.

I know that for loops are possible but I have realized that they are not optimal.

Comment: You could split it in a list i.e. `split(V, V)` and if you need individual vector objects in the global environment. use `list2env(setNames(split(V,V), c('P', 'N')), envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, consider marking them as "accepted answer" by ticking the grey tick under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic atomic vector operations:

```
V = c("J", "J", "J", "N", "N")
P = V[V == "J"]
D = which(V == "J")

> P
[1] "J" "J" "J"
> D
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing vector operations, the function subset does this.

```
P = subset(V, V == 'J')
```

Comment: You guys are golden. Thank you!